# Why glDrawElements is interfering with glGetBufferSubData when using the same buffer for Compute Shading and rendering

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a program that renders a stream of points. The method used to acquire the points for a given frame have strong temporal coherence, thus, in the rendering loop, first, I use a Compute Shader to compact the stream, removing unwanted points. Second, I add new points to the set. Finally, I render it using `glDrawElements`.

That's the code which do the process ( it uses Qt to manipulate OpenGL ):

```
template< typename Vec3 >
unsigned int CompactionRenderingState< Vec3 >::render()
{
    // Compact stream.
    m_nElements = compact();

    // Sends new points to GPU.
    QOpenGLBuffer* buffer = m_outputBuffers[ POS ];
    buffer->bind();
    buffer->write( m_nElements * BYTES_PER_VERTEX, ( void * ) &RenderingState::m_positions[ 0 ],
                   RenderingState::m_positions.size() * BYTES_PER_VERTEX );

    buffer = m_outputBuffers[ ATTRIB0 ];
    buffer->bind();
    buffer->write( m_nElements * BYTES_PER_VERTEX, ( void * ) &RenderingState::m_colors[ 0 ],
                   RenderingState::m_colors.size() * BYTES_PER_VERTEX );

    m_nElements += RenderingState::m_positions.size();

    // Draws the resulting points.
    m_arrayObj->bind();

    unsigned int bufferOffset = 0;
    switch( RenderingState::m_attribs )
    {
        case Attributes::NORMALS:
        {
            RenderingState::m_painter->setStandardEffect( QGL::LitMaterial );

            m_outputBuffers[ POS ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &bufferOffset );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Position );

            m_outputBuffers[ ATTRIB0 ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Normal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &bufferOffset );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Normal );

            break;
        }
        case Attributes::COLORS:
        {
            m_renderingProgram->bind();

            m_outputBuffers[ POS ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &bufferOffset );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Position );

            m_outputBuffers[ ATTRIB0 ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Color, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &bufferOffset );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Color );

            break;
        }
        case Attributes::COLORS_AND_NORMALS:
        {
            throw logic_error( "Colors and normals not supported yet." );
            break;
        }
    }

    m_openGL->glMemoryBarrier( GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BARRIER_BIT );
    m_openGL->glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, m_nElements );

    m_openGL->glDisableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Position );
    m_openGL->glDisableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Normal );
    m_openGL->glDisableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Color );

    m_openGL->glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
    m_renderingProgram->release();
    m_arrayObj->release();

    // Swaps buffers for the next frame.
    for( int i = 0; i < N_BUFFER_TYPES; ++i )
    {
        std::swap( m_inputBuffers[ i ], m_outputBuffers[ i ] );
    }
}

template< typename Vec3 >
unsigned int CompactionRenderingState< Vec3 >::compact()
{
    // Makes the compaction of the unused points.
    unsigned int nElements = m_compactionFlags.size();
    unsigned int nBlocks = ( unsigned int ) ceil( ( float ) nElements / BLOCK_SIZE );
    nElements = m_scan.doScan( m_compactionFlags );

    m_openGL->glBindBufferBase( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, Scan::N_BUFFER_TYPES + POS, m_inputBuffers[ POS ]->bufferId() );
    m_openGL->glBindBufferBase( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, Scan::N_BUFFER_TYPES + ATTRIB0,
                                m_inputBuffers[ ATTRIB0 ]->bufferId() );
    m_openGL->glBindBufferBase( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, Scan::N_BUFFER_TYPES + N_BUFFER_TYPES + POS,
                                m_outputBuffers[ POS ]->bufferId() );
    m_openGL->glBindBufferBase( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, Scan::N_BUFFER_TYPES + N_BUFFER_TYPES + ATTRIB0,
                                m_outputBuffers[ ATTRIB0 ]->bufferId() );

    m_compactionProgram->bind();
    m_compactionProgram->enableAttributeArray( "flags" );
    m_compactionProgram->enableAttributeArray( "prefixes" );
    m_compactionProgram->enableAttributeArray( "inputVertices" );
    m_compactionProgram->enableAttributeArray( "inputAttrib0" );
    m_compactionProgram->enableAttributeArray( "outputVertices" );
    m_compactionProgram->enableAttributeArray( "outputAttrib0" );

    m_openGL->glDispatchCompute( nBlocks, 1, 1 );
    m_openGL->glMemoryBarrier( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT );

    m_compactionProgram->disableAttributeArray( "flags" );
    m_compactionProgram->disableAttributeArray( "prefixes" );
    m_compactionProgram->disableAttributeArray( "inputVertices" );
    m_compactionProgram->disableAttributeArray( "inputAttrib0" );
    m_compactionProgram->disableAttributeArray( "outputVertices" );
    m_compactionProgram->disableAttributeArray( "outputAttrib0" );

    m_openGL->glBindBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0 );

    return nElements;
}
```

====== EDITED ======

I have writen an automated test to check the whole process. This test compacts an array of point positions and another of attributes in such a way that data in odd indices are deleted. When I run the code under gdb with address space randomization disabled, it passes flawlessly. However, when run without gdb or with addres space randomization enabled in gdb, the returned arrays have all zeroes unless I comment `glDrawArrays` in the method `render()`.

====== END OF EDITED ======

```
TEST_F( CompactionTest, Compaction )
    {
        QGuiApplication app( g_argc, g_argv );

        QSurfaceFormat format;
        format.setVersion( 4, 3 );
        format.setRenderableType( QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL );
        format.setSwapBehavior( QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer );
        format.setSamples( 16 );

        unsigned int nElements = 3000;
        vector< unsigned int  > flags( nElements );
        vector< vec3 > pos( nElements );
        vector< vec3 > attrib0( nElements );

        for( int i = 0; i < nElements; ++i )
        {
            flags[ i ] = i % 2;
            pos[ i ] = vec3( i, i, i );
            attrib0[ i ] = vec3( i + nElements, i + nElements, i + nElements );
        }

        CompactionQGLView window( flags, pos, attrib0, format );
        window.resize(640, 480);
        window.show();

        app.exec();

        pos = window.m_compactedPos;
        attrib0 = window.m_compactedAttrib0;

        ASSERT_EQ( pos.size(), nElements * 0.5 );
        ASSERT_EQ( attrib0.size(), nElements * 0.5 );

        float expected = 1.;
        for( int i = 0; i < pos.size(); ++i, expected += 2 )
        {
            vec3 expectedVec( expected, expected, expected );
            cout << "Pos: " << pos[ i ] << ". Expected: " << expectedVec << endl;
            ASSERT_EQ( pos[ i ], expectedVec );

            expectedVec = vec3( expected + nElements, expected + nElements, expected + nElements );
            cout << "Attrib0: " << attrib0[ i ] << ". Expected: " << expectedVec << endl << endl;
            ASSERT_EQ( attrib0[ i ], expectedVec );
        }
    }
```

This next function reads the compaction results and is used by the `window` in the test to set `m_compactedPos` and `m_compactedAttrib0`.

```
template< typename Vec3 >
vector< vector< Vec3 > > CompactionRenderingState< Vec3 >::getResultCPU()
{
    m_openGL->glMemoryBarrier( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT );

    unsigned int resultSize = sizeof( Vec3 ) * m_nElements;
    Vec3* result = ( Vec3* ) malloc( resultSize );

    vector< vector< Vec3 > > results;

    for( int i = 0; i < N_BUFFER_TYPES; ++i )
    {
        if( m_inputBuffers[ i ] != NULL )
        {
            m_openGL->glBindBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, m_inputBuffers[ i ]->bufferId() );
            m_openGL->glGetBufferSubData( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, resultSize, ( void * ) result );

            vector< Vec3 > tempVec( m_nElements );
            std::copy( result, result + m_nElements, tempVec.begin() );
            results.push_back( tempVec );
        }
    }

    free( result );

    return results;
}
```

====== EDITED ======

So, what could be the possible causes for this bug occurring only when Address Space Randomization is enabled? I'm stuck and has been several days trying to figure this out. Any ideas?

====== END OF EDITED ======

Comment: If this issue only shows up in release builds, my gut tells me it's not OpenGL related. That is the sort of thing that happens when you have uninitialized memory or overrun some array. Debug vs. release definitely would not change any GL synchronization behavior.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Is the OP using the right barrier bit? I'm not very familiar with them, but from a quick read, `GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT` also sounds like it might be related. `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT` on the other hands sounds like it's a barrier for GPU access, not read-backs to the CPU. Not sure at all though without diving into it much more... Adding `GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT` might be worth a try, just to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I have used the suggested barried, but the problem still the same.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: The difference between the two really has to do with _what_ type of operation is viewing the buffer memory. `GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARIER` enforces visibility when you read/write data using GL commands, `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER` is basically for correctly ordering memory access between compute shader dispatches. So, yes, the correct barrier here would be `UPDATE`, but if it works in debug and not release then I would be hesitant to blame that; in the worst case scenario when you cannot figure out the kind of barrier you need you can always try `GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman After a lot of debugging I figured out that the problem was not related with the code being in Debug or Release mode, since the test fails in both cases when running under gdb with Address Space Randomization enabled. I have edited the question to reflect these conclusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was a subtle wrong implicit type casting ocurring when calling glVertexAttribPointer.

`void glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint  index,  GLint  size,  GLenum  type,  GLboolean  normalized,  GLsizei  stride,  const GLvoid *  pointer)` receives as last parameter a `const GLvoid *  pointer`. In my code I was passing the address of the variable `unsigned int bufferOffset` as this last parameter. That should be leading to some internal mess on OpenGL.

To fix the code, we just need to change the `glVertexAttribPointer` calls at the `switch` clause at the `render()` function:

```
switch( RenderingState::m_attribs )
    {
        case Attributes::NORMALS:
        {
            RenderingState::m_painter->setStandardEffect( QGL::LitMaterial );

            m_outputBuffers[ POS ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ( void * ) 0 );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Position );

            m_outputBuffers[ ATTRIB0 ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Normal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ( void * ) 0 );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Normal );

            break;
        }
        case Attributes::COLORS:
        {
            m_renderingProgram->bind();

            m_outputBuffers[ POS ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ( void * ) 0 );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Position );

            m_outputBuffers[ ATTRIB0 ]->bind();
            m_openGL->glVertexAttribPointer( QGL::Color, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ( void * ) 0 );
            m_openGL->glEnableVertexAttribArray( QGL::Color );

            break;
        }
        case Attributes::COLORS_AND_NORMALS:
        {
            throw logic_error( "Colors and normals not supported yet." );
            break;
        }
    }
```